# Discord.py silence command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been asking lots of questions lately about discord.py and this is one of them.

Sometimes there are those times when some people spam your discord server but kicking or banning them seems too harsh. I had the idea for a `silence` command which would delete every new message on a channel for a given amount of time.

My code so far is:

```
@BSL.command(pass_context = True)
async def silence(ctx, lenghth = None):
        if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.administrator or ctx.message.author.id == ownerID:
             global silentMode
             global silentChannel
             silentChannel = ctx.message.channel
             silentMode = True
             lenghth = int(lenghth)
             if lenghth != '':
                  await asyncio.sleep(lenghth)
                  silentMode = False
             else:
                  await asyncio.sleep(10)
                  silentMode = False
        else:
             await BSL.send_message(ctx.message.channel, 'Sorry, you do not have the permissions to do that @{}!'.format(ctx.message.author))
```

The code in my `on_message` section is:

```
if silentMode == True:
        await BSL.delete_message(message)
        if message.content.startswith('bsl;'):
                await BSL.process_commands(message)
```

All the variables used are pre-defined at the top of the bot.

My problem is that the bot deletes all new messages in all channels which it has access to. I tried putting `if silentChannel == ctx.message.channel` in the `on_message` section but this made the command stop working completely.

Any suggestions as to why this is happening are much appreciated.

Comment: Try printing out silentChannel and ctx.message.channel and check if they visually match

Comment: @Tim I used `print(silentChannel, ' - ', message.channel)` just under `on_message`. When I haven't ran the command the output would just be `  -  chat` (which is the name of the channel). After running the command, two channel names started appearing (as expected). This time the output was `chat2  -  chat`. `chat` kept changing to different channel names but `chat2` would always stay the same. I think this is the desired result as we want messages deleted only in one channel. I'm really not sure what's the problem now.

Comment: I would instead have a global container (probably a `set`) of silent channels.  Then you can just `silent_channels.add(ctx.message.channel)` and `silent_channels.discard(ctx.message.channel)` as appropriate.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not familiar with what you described here. Could you give me the syntax for a basic silence command using this? If there is not enough space, you can post it as an answer which will most likely be what I'm looking for anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
silent_channels = set()

@BSL.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel in silent_channels:
        if not message.author.server_permissions.administrator and  message.author.id != ownerID:
            await BSL.delete_message(message)
            return
    await BSL.process_commands(message)

@BSL.command(pass_context=True)
async def silent(ctx, length=0): # Corrected spelling of length
    if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.administrator or ctx.message.author.id == ownerID:
        silent_channels.add(ctx.message.channel)
        await BSL.say('Going silent.')
        if length:
            length = int(length)
            await asyncio.sleep(length)
            if ctx.message.channel not in silent_channels: # Woken manually
                return
            silent_channels.discard(ctx.message.channel)
            await BSL.say('Waking up.')

@BSL.command(pass_context=True)
async def wake(ctx):
    silent_channels.discard(ctx.message.channel)
```

Should work (I haven't tested it, testing bots is a pain).  Searching through sets is fast, so doing it for every message shouldn't be a real burden on your resources.

Comment: This is just what I wanted. Works perfectly (with minor alterations to suit my needs). Accepted answer :)