# DM commands to discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I recently had the idea of DMing my bot commands. For example, a command which would unban me from every server that the bot is on.

Unfortunately I don't have any starting point for the command because I'm not even sure DMing commands is possible.

Keywords like `discord.py`, `command` or `DM` are so common in google that finding any good info on the topic is very hard.

I'm looking for a way for the bot to receive DMs as commands and only accept them from me (my ID is stored in the variable `ownerID` if anyone wants to share any code).

While I'm mostly looking for the above, some code for the DM `unban` command would also be very helpful.

EDIT: I was asked to show some example code from my bot. Here is the code for the command `number` which generates a random number and sends it in a message. I hope this gives you an idea of how my bot is made:

```
@BSL.command(pass_context = True)
async def number(ctx, minInt, maxInt):
    if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.send_messages or ctx.message.author.id == ownerID:
        maxInt = int(maxInt)
        minInt = int(minInt)
        randomInt = random.randint(minInt, maxInt)
        randomInt = str(randomInt)
        await BSL.send_message(ctx.message.channel, 'Your random number is: ' + randomInt)
    else:
        await BSL.send_message(ctx.message.channel, 'Sorry, you do not have the permissions to do that @{}!'.format(ctx.message.author))
```

Comment: You haven't posted any of your current code. How do you expect to get help. Depending on how you'd written your bot accepting dms as commands would be different.

Comment: That's true. Sorry about that. I will add some example code from my bot as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send commands in private messages.  Something like

```
@BSL.command(pass_context=True)
async def unban(ctx):
    if ctx.message.channel.is_private and ctx.message.author.id == ownerID:
        owner = await BSL.get_user_info(ownerID)
        await BSL.say('Ok {}, unbanning you.'.format(owner.name))
        for server in BSL.servers:
            try:
                await BSL.unban(server, owner) # I think having the same name should be fine.  If you see weird errors this may be why.
                await BSL.say('Unbanned from {}'.format(server.name))
            except discord.HTTPException as e:
                await BSL.say('Unbanning failed in {} because\n{}'.format(server.name, e.text))
            except discord.Forbidden:
                await BSL.say('Forbidden to unban in {}'.format(server.name))
    else:
        if ctx.message.author.id != ownerID:
            await BSL.say('You are not my owner')
        if not ctx.message.channel.is_private:
            await BSL.say('This is a public channel')
```

should work. I'm not sure what happens if you try to unban a user who is not banned, that may be what raises `HTTPException`

Comment: This does not seem to work. There is no error message or output to discord.

Comment: @user9123 I can get it to tell me that my bot can't unban people.  How are you saving your `ownerid`?  I think that `ctx.message.author.id` is a string.

Comment: I simply saved it as `ownerID = '34481235886840217'` which indeed is a string. The variable has a capital I and D but I changed those in your code when I pasted it into my bot.

Comment: @user9123 I added a response indicating that the command was received from the owner in a private channel.  Try the updated code, it should at least tell us where the problem is.

Comment: Okay, turns out this is partially my fault as I forgot to use the bot prefix, however, when I used the bot prefix I got the following `discord.errors.Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): Cannot execute action on a DM channel`.

Comment: Which line?  Sounds like a permissions issue.  Does your bot have permission to send people private messages?

Comment: Hmmm, upon further inspection it turns out that the error is caused by the `delete_message` in `on_message`. I don't want to change this because it would cause more problems than it might solve. Any way to bypass this? Also, yes, mu bot has permissions to send people PMs because I used it to PM myself before.

Comment: The one you ask about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48713510/discord-py-silence-command)?  Just change the conditional to `if message.channel in silent_channels and not message.channel.is_private:`

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Thanks for your help. The command works like a charm.