# discord.py How to add Mute command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot and I really want to make a mute command to mute toxic users.
This is the code I've currently [done](http://prntscr.com/ids1sp), this isn't the rewrite version.

```
    @bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def mute(ctx, user_id, userName: discord.User):
    if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.administrator:
        user = ctx.message.author
        role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="Muted")
        await client.add_roles(user, role)
     else:
       embed=discord.Embed(title="Permission Denied.", description="You don't have permission to use this command.", color=0xff00f6)
       await bot.say(embed=embed)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to know how to make a mute command. Up above is my current code and it doesnt work and I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: "Why isn't my code working" is considered off topic on Stack overflow.

Comment: and if you know how, how would I also add a time interval e.g >mute @toxicuser 60m

Comment: @chrisz No it's not. @Leighton.  Keep a dictionary or set of Users that have been muted, and the `mute` command just adds them to that list. Then in your `on_message` event you can call `delete_message` on their messages.  [See this similar question about muting channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48713510/discord-py-silence-command)

Answer (score 3):

I rewritten my code and got a working peice of code, here it is if others need it :)

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
     if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.administrator or ctx.message.author.id == '194151340090327041':
        role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name='Muted')
        await bot.add_roles(member, role)
        embed=discord.Embed(title="User Muted!", description="**{0}** was muted by **{1}**!".format(member, ctx.message.author), color=0xff00f6)
        await bot.say(embed=embed)
     else:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Permission Denied.", description="You don't have permission to use this command.", color=0xff00f6)
        await bot.say(embed=embed)
```

Comment: message.author.id is an int so you should do `ctx.message.author.id == 194151340090327041`

Answer (score 2):

you should use this :

```
await member.edit(mute = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I fixed some things in the code if neither of his work for you try mine and change things accordingly

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
     if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.administrator:
        role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name='Muted')
        await ctx.add_roles(member, role)
        embed=discord.Embed(title="User Muted!", description="**{0}** was muted by **{1}**!".format(member, ctx.message.author), color=0xff00f6)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
     else:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Permission Denied.", description="You don't have permission to use this command.", color=0xff00f6)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When posting modified code as an answer, please help the OP and other users understand what you fixed and why with a written explanation. "I fixed some things" requires people to both hunt for the changes and, when they have found them, wonder why you have changed these things.