# Discord - can I mute others in the voice channel from a python code?

Tags: python, discord

Is it possible to mute (not server mute, just self mute) someone in the voice channel from a python script?
Is there a discord API? Or maybe a discord bot can do that or other ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I need that the code will mute person A for me.

Comment: First result in google, may be of use - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753630/discord-py-how-to-add-mute-command

Comment: No, you can't. You can only server mute someone. Why not just server mute them?

Comment: @sairamkumar because I need to split the voice channel into "rooms" that can change in seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your request is not possible with discord.

The sound from your microphone is being directed to the discord server, and the server then distributes the sound to the persons in the chat.

Like [this post](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360030317512-New-feature-Mute-for-specific-person) shows there seems to be no way to do this in Discord

Comment: Is this a server mute? I need "self mute" as I said. I need somehow to split the voice channel to "rooms" that changed every like 10 seconds. and I don't want to move voice channels every 10 seconds.

Comment: That's a self mute

Comment: The bot should self mute A just for B (just B won't hear A). Are you sure the post helps in this situation? (if so I will read and learn more on discord bots)

Comment: So you want everyone to hear you except for one person?

Comment: Exactly! Then I can create "rooms". Just the people in my room will hear me. I can run code on their computer, so the problem is - can I mute myself from their computer from the code?

Comment: I can't find any solution, does this post help you? Did you see it before that someone has done this exact thing you're trying to do? I just want to help you out my friend.

Comment: Well, you can do self-bot, but it is strictly not recommended.

Comment: Well, I didn't see anything like that before, I just thought it will allow me to use discord and create "rooms" inside instead of writing the voice chat by myself. Actually, I run code on the clients' computers anyway, do you know a way to mute others from the code (the code on computer A will mute B for computer A)?

Comment: @sairamkumar what do you mean by self-bot and why it's not recommended? Thanks!

Comment: it's a bot running on user account, it's against discord's TOS and might get you banned.