# "commands" is not defined in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Code:

```
import os
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands

GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')
client2 = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break
    print(
        f'{client.user} has connected to '
        f'{guild.name}'
        )

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user.name} has connected to Discord!')


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@client2.command(pass_context = True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
     if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.administrator or ctx.message.author.id == '194151340090327041':
        role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name='Muted')
        await bot.add_roles(member, role)
        embed=discord.Embed(title="User Muted!", description="**{0}** was muted by **{1}**!".format(member, ctx.message.author), color=0xff00f6)
        await bot.say(embed=embed)
     else:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Permission Denied.", description="You don't have permission to use this command.", color=0xff00f6)
        await bot.say(embed=embed)

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

I am trying to create a bot that mutes people. This is my 1st week in learning the discord API. I copied the `mute` function from a website so I didn't code everything myself. I'm having some trouble with the command. The error is:

```
NameError: name 'commands' is not defined
```

But I have seen other people do this and not get an error so I have no idea what the problem is.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried importing `discord.ext.commands`?

Comment: Why do you use `client` and `client2`? If you want to use `commands` import `from discord.ext import commands` and remove `client`

Comment: You've also never defined the original `client` variable...

Comment: Ok now I know what I did wrong. but how can I fix these many many mistakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned before, you are going around with definitions that don't exist/that you shouldn't use.

**First:** Decide between `client` or `bot` and use the original handling, not somehow `client2` etc.

**Second:** To use the commands, import `from discord.ext import commands`.

**Third:** Since you are now using `client` the commands have to be adapted. Also you don't use `client.say` or `bot.say` anymore, but `ctx.send`.

**Fourth**: You can't use multiple `on_ready` events, combine them or just use one.

**Fifth:** Please have a look at the mute command as yours contained many errors and requested things in the wrong way. You can take a look at other StackOverflow questions and answers as just [copy and pasting another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753630/discord-py-how-to-add-mute-command) is not really useful...

Have a look at the **full/final code:**

```py
from discord.utils import get # New import
import discord
from discord.ext import commands # New import

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'YourPrefixHere') # Changes
TOKEN = "YourTokenHere" # Changes

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user.name} has connected to Discord!')


@client.command()
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.administrator or ctx.message.author.id == 'Your_ID': # Changes
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Muted') # Changes
        await member.add_roles(role)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="User Muted!",
                              description="**{}** was muted by **{}**!".format(member, ctx.message.author),
                              color=0xff00f6)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
     else:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Permission Denied.", description="You don't have permission to use this command.", color=0xff00f6)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

client.run(TOKEN) # Changes
```