# Temp Mute command

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to make it so server **moderators** are able to temporarily mute users in their **Discord**. I am not an experienced developer within Discord bots but learning.

What I am trying to do?
I am trying to make it so server owners are able to temp mute users in their Discord servers.

This is what I currently have for my Mute command:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def mute(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.kick_members:
        role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="Muted")
        embed = discord.Embed(title="{} has been muted!".format(user.name), description="When the user needs unmuting do !unmute @user!" , color=0x0072ff)
        embed.set_footer(text="Reversed by Damian#9209 | Reduction#9975")
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
        await bot.add_roles(user, role)
        await bot.say(embed=embed)
    else:
       embed = discord.Embed(title="Permission Denied.", description="You don't have permission to use this command.", color=0xff0000)
       embed.set_footer(text="Reversed by Damian#9209 | Reduction#9975")
       await bot.say(embed=embed)
```

Comment: What is your question? (Edit it into the question instead of commenting)

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discord.py silence command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48713510/discord-py-silence-command)

Comment: Not sure it is. I am looking to have a time on the mute.

Comment: In that case, I would instead maintain some mapping of users and timestamps.  Whenever you receive a message from a user in the mapping, you check the current time against that timestamp.  If that time hasn't come yet, delete the message.  If it has come, remove the user from the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

As I am sure you are aware, the Discord.py library has changed to no longer include the rewrite branch. This means that the mute command has been made way easier for you. I'll provide some code to get you started. I will also provide links to all the documentation to each line.

```
@bot.command(name="tempmute",description="Temporarily mute a member")
@commands.has_permission(mute_members=True)
async def _tempmute(ctx,user:discord.Member):
    muteRole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles,name="Muted")
    await user.add_roles(muteRole)
```

[has_permission](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_permissions#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions) is a check for Discord user permissions

[utils.get](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=utils%20get#discord.utils.get) is a utility function that can step through iterables and find the correct search filter. Here, we are using it to find a role with the name "Muted"

[add_roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add_roles#discord.Member.add_roles) is a coroutine function (aka needs to be awaited) that adds one or multiple roles to a user.

I suggest also making sure that the role has the `speak` permission disabled so that you don't have to deal with it through the `on_message` event. Hope that helps!